# Check that $f(x,y)=y^{-1}e^{-y-x/y}$ is a joint density function on $x>0$, $y>0$

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

> Consider
>   $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}e^{-\left(y+\frac{x}{y}\right)} , \qquad 0<x,y<\infty$$
>   Verify that $f$ is a joint density function.

$$\int^{y=\infty}_{y=0} \int^{x=\infty}_{x=0}\frac{1}{y} e^{-\left(y+\frac x y \right)} \, dx \, dy$$

$$=-\int^{y=\infty}_{y=0} \left. e^{-\left(y+\frac x y \right)} \right|^\infty_0 \, dy$$

$$=\int^{y=\infty}_{y=0}1 \, dy$$

This does not become $1$. How do I prove it is a joint density function, then?

Comment: In your final integral, the integrand should be $e^{-y}$, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there's missing minus sign: you need
$$
\left. -e^{-\left( y + \frac x y \right)} \right|_0^\infty
$$

Instead of
$$
\left. -e^{-\left(y+\frac x y \right)} \right|^\infty_0
$$
it can be useful to write
$$
\left. -e^{-\left(y+\frac x y \right)} \right|^\infty_{x=0},
$$
reminding you *which* variable goes from $0$ to $\infty$.  The $y$ is still a free variable in this expression.  So you get
$$
\Big( \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-\left( y + \frac x y \right)} \Big)- \Big(-e^{-\left( y + \frac 0 y \right)} \Big)
$$
which is $0 - \Big( -e^{-y}\Big),$ or $e^{-y}.$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-\left( y + \frac x y \right)} = 0. \qquad$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : I didn't explain that point at all; I left some details as an exercise. I wasn't attempting to do the whole problem, but just to comment on the part where an error occurred. $\qquad$